# UseState() - change variable block and reset my input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

I'm trying to change value in my `Typography` tag when I'm writting into my `input`.

But, when I press my keyboard for the first time, my `input` unfocus and reset. The letter I pressed appears into my `Typography` tag.

I don't understand why I can't continue to write into my input ?

```
const [mJustice, setmJustice] = useState("");

const handleChange = () => {
    setmJustice(selectM);
}

<Box>
    <Typography id={ministry.id} variant="body" componant="p">
        {mJustice}
    </Typography>

    <input
        placeholder="Prénom et nom"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'description', 'maxLength': 24 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
const [mJustice, setmJustice] = useState("");

const handleChange = () => {
    setmJustice(selectM);
}

<Box>
    <Typography id={ministry.id} variant="body" componant="p">
        {mJustice}
    </Typography>

    <input
        placeholder="Prénom et nom"
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'description', 'maxLength': 24 }}
        value={mJustice}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
</Box>
```

Comment: That work better than previous time, but I have to re-click on my input to continues to write. Because each time I press my keyboard, the input unselect my cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Form elements such as  has its own state and update it based on user input. Using "single source of truth concept", create a controlled component where React component controls form it rendered.

```
 <input
    placeholder="Prénom et nom"
    value={mJustice}
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'description', 'maxLength': 24 }}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, that improve my code, but I have always to click on my input for each letter I want to write.

Comment: Maybe your handleChange function should be as follows, but I've no idea about the issue you are talking:
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setmJustice(event.target.value);
  };